# Error: Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

This is my build.gradle(app)

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.0'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:1.2.0'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:1.2.0'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:1.2.0'
}
```

These are my dependencies in build.gradle(project):

```
{ 
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.1'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.1'
}
```

Can anyone please help with what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: please post the full gradle file

Comment: and the full error code please

Comment: Share your full error message.

Answer (score 0):

Check google services version and it is not compatible with the gradle version.

```
{ 
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.1'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.1'
}
```

Try to downgrade or upgrade google services version.

Answer (score 0):

Missing some of your gradle and log information I give it a try, but I might be wrong:

**Build (Project level)** (3.2.1 doesn't exists, it is 3.1.2)

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.1'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.2'
}
```

**Build (app level)**

```
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:15.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.0'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:2.3.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:15.0.0'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:1.2.0'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:1.2.0'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:1.2.0'
```

(*appcompat downgraded, firebase upgraded, compile replaced by implementation*), I had similar problem with appcompat and downgrading to 27.0.2 solved for me

Comment: Build project level 3.2.1 is there. I did what you have suggested but getting same error

Comment: @Ari strange.. If I use 3.2.1 I get error for not existing, and I have last android studio version.. Try provide fill grade file, both please

Answer (score 0):

You can't use firebase-ui 1.2.0.

Check the [compatibility here](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android#compatibility-with-firebase--google-play-services-libraries):

```
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:3.3.1'
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:3.3.1'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:3.3.1'
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:3.3.1'
```

Then use the same version of Google play services libraries and firebase libraries:

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:15.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:15.0.0'
```